# Registering custom broadcast for a network event

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use a third party SIP implementation in my Android app. Since I want to support version older then 2.3, I cant use the SIP framework build into Gingerbread. 
Do I need a constantly running service that will listen for the SIP call?

As far as I know, services are not meant to be run constantly, and listening to events like incoming calls or SMS is done by the system itself, which will broadcast it system-wide. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Isn't a BroadcastReceiver what you want?

Comment: Yes, it probably is. But what broadcasts would it receive? The question pretty much is as fallows - can I register a custom broadcast that will be sent out when someone calls my SIP app.